# C parse content of a file

Tags: c, file

I have to parse the content of a file: a string is given as input and I have to search for each letter in the string into the content of my file. So my first tought was

```
while (readBytes = read(fd, buffer, sizeof(char)) > 0);
```

but how do I make sure to get access to each char that is into the file? Is it enough using

```
for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
{
   parseChar(buffer[i]);
}
```

what if the content of my file is greater then `SIZE`?

Comment: Why not just read from the file one character at a time, e.g. using `getchar()` ?

Answer (score 1):

Don't read the whole file if you don't have to. Read some data with `read` and call `parseChar` for every character read. Repeat until you reach end of file.

```
while (readBytes = read(fd, buffer, BUFFER_LENGTH) > 0)
{
    for (i = 0; i < readBytes; i++)
    {
        parseChar(buffer[i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can determine the size of file using `ftell`, then repeated call this function ( each time fp will get advanced to next position ), thus can parse whole file 
.